# Net force of a falling down people by Resolution of Force.

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image: Fall People]

From the picture, I want to calculate the Force (F) when people fall down. I searched the internet, but I have no findings. Given that Mass (M) = 75 kg, Gravitational force (G) = 9.81 N. How can I calculate the Force (F)? Thank you.

Comment: @DavidZ  This is not "homework". I just DON'T KNOW so I ask. That's all.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's homework or not; the type of question you've written isn't suitable for the site. See the notice above for information about how you could change it to make it suitable.